# Axios GET request to node server never returns logged in user, visiting same route manually in browser does

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, auth0

I have a node server running on `localhost:8000`, which spits out the currently logged in user at `/user`. Now in my frontend on `localhost:8001` I'd like to retrieve that user.

If I manually go to `localhost:8000/user` in my *browser* I do get back the user, provided I am logged in. Whenever I am logged out, an empty string is returned. So far, so good.

However: whenever I send a request to `localhost:8000/user` from my *frontend*, I do get the empty string. So it is working (I don't get any errors, and status code is `200`), but it seems like my frontend does not *know* that I am logged in / my backend does not realise that I am logged in.

**Frontend**

```
axios.get("localhost:8000/user").then(res => {
    console.log(res)
  }) //this works, but always behaves like there is no current 
     //user i.e. that I am logged-out
```

**Backend**

```
//imports here, then:    
passport.use(
  new Auth0Strategy(
    {
      domain: "bla.eu.auth0.com",
      clientID: "afjgnrtkngewmofmwlefmlwems",
      clientSecret:
        "jngnsknkankjangkjangjknKJJKGKAHBJVvgjvVgjVbhJBjhbJbj",
      callbackURL: "http://localhost:8000/callback",
      audience: "https://bla.eu.auth0.com/userinfo",
      responseType: "code",
      scope: "openid email profile",
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, extraParam, profile, done) {
      return done(null, profile)
    }
  )
)

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user)
})

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user)
})

const app = express()
app.use(cors({ origin: "http://localhost:8001" }))

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

app.use(
  session({ secret: "secret_key", resave: true, saveUninitialized: true })
)

app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.loggeedIn = false
  if (req.session.passport && typeof req.session.passport.user !== undefined) {
    res.locals.loggedIn = true
  }
  next()
})

app.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
  res.send("Root")
})

app.get(
  "/login",
  passport.authenticate(
    "auth0",
    {
      domain: "bla.auth0.com",
      clientID: "kafmkafmkamfkamfka",
      redirectUri: "http://localhost:8000/callback",
      audience: "https://bla.auth0.com/userinfo",
      responseType: "code",
      scope: "openid email profile",
    },
    function(req, res, next) {
      res.redirect("/")
    }
  )
)

app.get("/logout", function(req, res, next) {
  req.logout()
  res.redirect("/")
})

app.get(
  "/callback",
  passport.authenticate("auth0", {
    failureRedirect: "/failure",
  }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect("/user")
  }
)

app.get("/user", function(req, res, next) {
  res.send(req.user)
})

app.get("/failure", function(req, res, next) {
  res.send("Failure")
})

app.listen(8000, function() {
  console.log("running")
})
```

Is there something I am not getting here? Is visiting the browser at `localhost:8000/user` and making an axios request to ``localhost:8000/user` **not** the same?

Answer (score 1):

Axios by default does not send cookies. You have to set enable cookies for sessions  to work by setting withCredentials option to true.

```
axios.get("localhost:8000/user", { withCredentials: true } ).then(res => {
    console.log(res)
  })
```

Comment: thanks! tried this, but now I'm getting a CORS error?